# Which part of a Mule message is considered immutable?

Tags: mule, mule-studio, anypoint-studio, mulesoft

Which part of a Mule message is considered immutable

1.Payload
2.Attachments
3.Variables

4.attributes

Answer (score 1):

In Mule 4 the payload, attributes and [variables](https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-runtime/4.3/about-mule-variables) are part of the [Mule Event](https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-runtime/4.3/about-mule-event). The payload and attributes are in the [message](https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-runtime/4.3/about-mule-message). The message and variables are in the event.

Both the message and the event are immutable.